# Detecting file size and do operation conditionally

Tags: shell-script, files, rm

In my `main_dir`, I have a lot of sub-folders say `DFT1` to `DFT150`, and in each directory, there is a file named `OSZICAR`. However, some of this would have file size 0.

So I would like to have a script, that goes into each folder and checks the size of `OSZICAR`, if it is below size of 10 bytes, then delete its `DFT` folder.

The pseudo-code (which doesn't work), I have is:

```
for f in *; do
 cd $f
 status=(check whether OZICAR has size below 10bytes)
 cd ..
 if (status); do
  rm -r $f
 fi 
done
```

Comment: With bash: `if [ ! -s file ] ; then`. Citing `man bash`: " -s file True if file exists and has a size greater than zero." I.e. `-s` = look for non-empty files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `find`:

```
find DFT*/OSZICAR -size -10c -printf "%h\0" | xargs -r0 rm -r
```

- `find` searches for all files inside a `DFT*` directory called `OSZICAR`, whose file size is below 10 bytes; the `c` means bytes.
- Then `find` prints the directory name `%h` where the file was found (`DFT105` for instance), terminated by a nullbyte `\0`
- This is piped to `xargs` which reads the line terminated by a nullbyte `-0` and calls `rm -r` on every of them.

I recommend to call the command without the `xargs` part, to check if everything works correctly, before deleting anything.

**Edit:** If your `find` doesn't accept the `-printf` (like OSX) option, use this instead:

```
find DFT*/OSZICAR -size -10c -exec sh -c 'rm -r $(dirname "$1")' sh {} \;
```

Comment: I just try: but it gives me error :     dhcp-18-189-47-44:CE-06-new-stuctures_backup wenxuanhuang$ find DFT*/OSZICAR -size -10c -printf "%h\0" 
find: -printf: unknown primary or operator

Comment: I am using Mac OS 10.9, but does this affect? Thank you.

Comment: @user40780 See my edit

Comment: Thank you, do you know where could I know about what does $(dirname "$1") mean? Thank you.

Comment: @user40780 find prints the paths of the files with a filesize below 10 bytes, dirname removes the filename part from the path, hence prints only the name of the directory containing the file (the one you want to delete), see `man dirname`